# How do you structure stacked BEM elements in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, bem, scss-mixins

I have been converting a large css file to sass for a customer, and I have had no issues until I ran into this part:

```
  .container__form__input-fields{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 4%;
  }
  .container__form__input-fields,
  .container__form__textarea {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .container__form__input-fields
  .form__input,
  .container__form__textarea textarea {
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $primary-color;
    padding: 10px;
    color: $primary-color;
    width: 90%;
  }
```

I thought the obvious solution would be to write

```
  &__input-fields,
  &__textarea {
    width: 48%;
  }
```

But nope, that just cancelled out the styling completely.
I can find lots of info on how to handle nested elements. But how do I handle nested stacked elements?
Would it be better to simply seperate these elements and style them individually?

The full sass

```
    $primary-color: #41b883;
$secondary-color: #34495e;
$primary-text-color: black;
$secondary-text-color: white;

::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: $secondary-text-color;
}
::-moz-input-placeholder{
  color: $secondary-text-color;
}
::-ms-input-placeholder{
  color: $secondary-text-color;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
        background-color: $primary-color;
        left: 33%;
        border: none;
        color: $secondary-text-color;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;

  &--secondary {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: $primary-color;
      top: 300px;
      left: 50px;
      border: none;
      color: $secondary-text-color;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;

  }
  &--tertiary {
    background: $primary-color;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: $secondary-text-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
.container {
  &__hero {
    position: relative;
  }
  &__hero__image {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  &__hero__text {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        color: $secondary-text-color;
        text-align: center;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        color: $secondary-text-color;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  .container__card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(19rem, 1fr));
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;

    &__wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 210px 210px 80px;
      grid-template-areas: "image" "text" "footer";
      border-radius: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      text-align: center;
      margin: 50px;
    }

      &__image {
        grid-area: image;
        background: url("~@/assets/website1.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        border-top-left-radius: 15px;
        border-top-right-radius: 15px;
      }
      &__text {
        grid-area: text;
        margin: 25px;
        h2 {
          margin-top: 5;
          font-size: 28px;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 15px;
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        &__upperTitle {
          font-size: 15px;
          color: green;
        }
      }
      &__footer {
        grid-area: footer;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        background-color: $primary-color;
        cursor: pointer;
        .fas {
          color: #fff !important;
          margin-top: 15px;
        }
      }
  }
  .container__about__hero {
    position: relative;
    &__image {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    &__text {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding-left: 50px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      font-size: 3.5em;
      color: $secondary-text-color;
      font-weight: 800;
    }
  }
  .container__about__main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    padding: 50px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    &__image {
      width: 70%;
      height: auto;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 3em;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
  }
  .container__form__wrapper {
    background: url("~@/assets/footer.jpeg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 140px;

  .container__form {
    max-width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  }
  .container__form__input-fields{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 4%;
  }
  .container__form__input-fields,
  .container__form__textarea {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .container__form__input-fields
  .form__input,
  .container__form__textarea textarea {
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $primary-color;
    padding: 10px;
    color: $primary-color;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .container__form__textarea textarea {
    height: 186px;
  }  
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 759px) {
    .container__hero {
      .container__hero__text {
        h1 {
          font-size: 1.3em;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 1.1em;
        }
        .btn {
          font-size: 15px;
          left: 27%;
          padding: 10px 26px;
        }
      }
    }
    .container__about__hero {
      &__text {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }
      .btn--secondary {
        font-size: 13px;
        top: 70%;
        left: 10%;
        padding: 10px 26px;
      }
    }
    .container__about__main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .container__about__main__image {
      width: 100%;

    }
    .container__form__wrapper {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That should work if the surrounding code is right. What does the complete sass code look like?

Comment: I put the full code in my post. Thank you